# How to create a grid of bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I have a problem in making layout boostrap.

I want to make something like this :
[image]

Is there anything wrong in my script?

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <p>Colum 1</p>
          </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
              <p>Colum 2</p>
         </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
               <p>Colum 3</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
              <p>Colum 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't nest `col-*` classes inside other `col-*` classes, they have to be wrapped by a `row` class. Now, this is my approach for do what you want on `Bootstrap 4`.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-3 text-center bg-info">
    Column A1
  </div>

  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 text-center bg-danger">
        <p>Column B1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center bg-primary">
        <p>Colum B2</p>
      </div>      
      <div class="col-9 text-center bg-warning">
        <p>Colum B3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>    
</div>
```

Note that I have removed the `md` breakpoint so you can see the layout without having to go fullscreen mode, and also added some utility classes like `bg-colors` to helps the visualization of the layout.

Comment: thanks and it works. I like the structure of the script above. :)

Answer (score 1):

This code will be helpful to you.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="height:700px;background:red;">
      <div class="" role="complementary">
                  col-md-3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="height:700px;"  >
      <div class="col-md-6" style="height:350px;background:green;">.col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:350px;background:pink;">.col-md-3</div>
         <div class="col-md-9" style="height:350px;background:blue;">.col-md-9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably a very nice by giving fixed size value in the column. Thanks a lot master

Comment: You are welcome, consider to upvote my answer if it works for you@SitiRahmah

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to create nested row.just try to experiment

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <p>Colum 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>Colum 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
           <p>Colum 3</p>
      </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
          <p>Colum 4</p>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Yeah I'll try to experiment in the front end, thanks for the advice. :D